# Erasure channel Kraus operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

I'm following these notes https://www.tcm.phy.cam.ac.uk/~sea31/tiqit_complete_notes.pdf where in Section 4.6, the erasure channel is said to have the following Kraus operators. Similar descriptions are found in other notes too.

$$M_{0}=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}{\sqrt{1-p}} & {0} & {0} \\ {0} & {\sqrt{1-p}} & {0} \\ {0} & {0} & {0}\end{array}\right) M_{1}=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}{0} & {0} & {\sqrt{p}} \\ {0} & {0} & {0} \\ {0} & {0} & {0}\end{array}\right) M_{2}=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}{0} & {0} & {0} \\ {0} & {0} & {\sqrt{p}} \\ {0} & {0} & {0}\end{array}\right)$$

I don't see how this works since $\sum_i M^\dagger_i M_i \neq I$. One instead gets 
$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}{1-p} & {0} & {0} \\ {0} & {1-p} & {0} \\ {0} & {0} & {2p}\end{array}\right)$$

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you also link other notes where you found this representation?

Comment: @expikx https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.1445.pdf (Section 4.7.6) also has this representation

Comment: My answer could be possibly wrong. Please consider Norbert's answer.

Comment: @user1936752 Wilde's notes you link in the comments do it right.  There it is stated: *"The output alphabet contains one more symbol than the input
alphabet, namely, the erasure symbol e."* -- The other notes you link, on the other hand, seem to have several shortcomings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Kraus operators for the channel are incorrect. The erasure channel acts on a qubit and outputs a qutrit.  In the (uncommon) convention
$$
\mathcal E(\rho) = \sum M_i^\dagger \rho M_i
$$
used in the paper, the correct matrices $M_i$ therefore need to have size $2\times 3$. They are exactly formed by the first two rows of the matrices above.

Then, you can indeed verify that $\sum_i M_i M_i^\dagger=I$, which in the convention above corresponds to a trace-preserving map.

Comment: My answer could be possibly wrong since I did not consider output being a qutrit. But I have certain doubts. Usually, the completeness relation for Kraus operators state $M_i^{\dagger}M_i = I$, but which is not the case here. I understand we get identity by considering the form you have mentioned. Also, I thought it could be non-unital because in the papers I have read, they usually classify erasure channels apart from unital channels. Apologies for confusion.

Comment: However, please tell me why can't trace-decreasing maps make no sense. There are trace-decreasing CP maps.

Comment: @expikx The erasure channel can be realized physically (deterministally).  Thus, it is trace preserving.  BTW, why do you put comments regarding *your* post under mine?  Note that the position of the dagger depends where it is put in the def. of the channel, which is non-standard here.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Could you advise on a good reference to read about the definition of the erasure Kraus operators that you used in your reply, and maybe a more conventional description of the channel? Thanks.